# Edit yaml files using js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

I am trying to edit a template-yaml file using a js function. The js function will get a `name of organization: org` and this will replace corresponding values in the template-yaml and generate a `org-yaml`.

My template-yaml file looks like this:

```
Organizations:
    - &Org3   # this line here is important.
        Name: Org3Name
        ID: Org3ID
```

I am using the below function:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');

const changeConfig = (org) => {
    // doc.Organizations[0] = org;
    doc.Organizations[0].Name = org + 'Name';
    doc.Organizations[0].ID = org + 'ID';
    fs.writeFileSync('new_file.yaml', yaml.dump(doc));
}

let doc = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./sample_yaml.yaml', 'utf-8'));
changeConfig('Org1');
```

I am getting is this:

```
Organizations:
  - Name: Org1MSP
    ID: Org1MSP
```

Is there some way I can modify to get a structure like this:

```
Organizations:
  - Org1  # notice this
    Name: Org1MSP
    ID: Org1MSP
```

Answer (score 1):

Kalinda, you can try this:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');

const changeConfig = (org) => {
    doc.Organizations[0][org] = {};
    delete doc.Organizations[0].Org;
    doc.Organizations[0][org].Name = org + 'Name';
    doc.Organizations[0][org].ID = org + 'ID';
    fs.writeFileSync('new_file.yaml', yaml.dump(doc));
}

let doc = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./sample_yaml.yaml', 'utf-8'));
changeConfig('Org2');
```

Sample yaml file:

```
Organizations:
    - Org:
        Name: OrgName
        ID: OrgID
```

if is correct, you need rename or create a new key in yaml file.

Result:

```
Organizations:
  - Org2:
      Name: Org2Name
      ID: Org2ID
```

When you use load methods, this methods transform your yaml file in plain object. So you can have better control over your object within javascript.